# Detect if a pipeline has been triggered after a branch is merged

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I'm currently triggering a CI for a repo with some docker files where I build the images and push them with a test tag to our private registry. It basically works like this:

1. Build the new image
2. Pushes a test tag to the registry with the name of current branch, e.g `test-my_feature`
3. The developers manually test it on the machines (Unfortunately this is not yet completely automatized so for the moment we are ok with doing manual testing)
4. Once they tested manually, we merge the branch
5. I remove manually the test tag from the registry.

I would like to make the last step automatically after the branch is merged. I have managed to remove a tag from the registry with a script on the ci however I'm not able to delete the right tag as I cannot get the name of the branch that has been merged. Is there a way to achieve that?

Expected behavior:

```yaml
remove-tag:
  stage: clean
  script:
    - ./remove_tag.sh $CI_LAST_MERGED_BRANCH # get here from somehere the name of the branch
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH # Only trigger in main branch
```